# Brewing with brettanomyces bruxellensis

Tags: brettanomyces, lambics

I got a good deal with some White Labs yeasts, including one Brettanomyces bruxellensis (WLP650), and I really don't know how to brew with it. Should I use it only for secondary or could I made a fruit lambic with an ale yeast?

**EDIT:** OK, simple question, do I need an ale yeast to ferment a Lambic with Brett?

Comment: That's a bit open ended.   We don't know what you like, so we can't tell you what to brew.   Brett. IPA?  Lambic?   Your own twist on Orval?  You could do any of these things, and more.   Can you narrow the scope of your question some?

Comment: Check out The Mad Fermentationist's blog post summarizing a lot of what you can do with Brett: http://www.themadfermentationist.com/2008/06/all-about-brettanomyces.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [White Labs' site](http://www.whitelabs.com/yeast/wlp650-brettanomyces-bruxellensis?s=homebrew), they say WLP650 was intended for secondary fermentation, but it would appear that if you use a yeast starter, you may be alright.

> Q: I am planning a sour brown ale with bret bruxellensis as the only yeast. Is there anything special I should do with this strain and is this a good idea?
>
> A. We don't recommend the vials for primary (not enough cells), but if you make a decent starter, it should be fine. You should plan on 3-5 days to grow up the starter, at least room temperature (but warmer is better) and aerate as usual. You are probably going to have to make twice as much of a starter as you normally would for Saccharomyces.